# Update Exists not working as expected in my code

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following 2 sample table and expected output. I am trying to achieve the below output using this query.

I need to check all the rows in my first table exists in second table, if exists updated with '365' otherwise keep the original data as it is.

I have written below query but it doesn't update the table and getting **"0 rows updated"**

```
UPDATE a1
SET code = 365
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM status
  WHERE status.aid = a1.aid
  AND status.side = a1.side
  AND status.year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)
  AND status.month = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)))
  AND status.completed = 1
);
```

I have table a1

```
Id aid side code
1  2    3       0
2  2    4       1
3  2    5       4
```

I have table status

```
Id  aid side year month completed
1     2  3     2023   3      1
2     2  4     2023   3      1
3     2  23    2022   2      1
```

**Output**

```
Id   aid   side   code
1    2     3      365
2    2     4      365
3    2     5        4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update will not work because you are correlating the rows on:

- ```
  WHERE status.aid = a1.aid
  AND status.side = a1.side
  ```

  Which will match the first two rows from `status` (not the third row).
- ```
  AND status.month = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)))
  ```

  Which only matches the third row from `status` (not the first two rows).

Therefore, there is no row that matches all the conditions in the correlated query so nothing will be updated.

If you do want to match then filter on the current (not the previous) month.

```sql
UPDATE a1
SET code = 365
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM status
  WHERE status.aid = a1.aid
  AND status.side  = a1.side
  AND status.year  = EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM sysdate)
  AND status.month = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate)
  AND status.completed = 1
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eUw-125N)